# Can't compile React Native Android APK, fails on bundleReleaseJsAndAssets/metro-bundler

Tags: android, react-native

I am getting the following errors compiling on Android, either from the command line or via Android Studio:

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task 'bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' during up-to-date check 

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/mikem/react/myapp/metro-bundler-symbolicate117923-49160-k3nnyf.htls935wmi.sock (Operation not supported on socket)
```

I have cleared out node_module and reset the caches, manually generated the bundle but this error continues.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In case anybody else runs into this - the link `metro-bundler-symbolicate117923-49160-k3nnyf.htls935wmi.sock` did exist in that directory  but had a root owner (perhaps could have been caused when I was trying to fix other issues).  Deleting the link fixed the problem.